# didn't send mail html body in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sendmail, database-trigger

I developed  a trigger in plsql, the trigger work but I received 6 mails in the same time. I need just one mail, how I can do it?

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER RI 
  AFTER insert or update on ap_supplier_sites_all 
  for each row 

DECLARE 
  x_count NUMBER;

begin

  select count(*) into x_count 
  from rib1 r1,rib2 r2 
  where r1.ATTRIBUTE4=r2.Supplier_RIB; 

  if(x_count > 0) 
  then 
     testrib;--execute SP
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Switching to an **after statement** trigger as @littlefoot suggests is correct **_if you must use a trigger_** but think about moving the email generation back to the application code. What happens if an error occurs before the transaction is committed or the user cancels (rollback) the transaction. Your email for the update has been sent but the update did not make it to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it goes:

- trigger fires when you insert or update rows in `AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL`

  - suppose you ran an `update` statement which updated 6 rows, something like this in Scott's `EMP` table:

    ```
    update emp set 
      sal = sal * 1.1
      where deptno = 20;
    ```
- trigger fires for each of those rows; if there are 6 rows updated, it fires 6 times
- it calculates number of rows in joined `rib1` and `rib2` tables

  - is it OK not to reference some "ID" column from `ap_supplier_sites_all`? Something like

    ```
    select count(*) into x_count 
    from rib1 r1, rib2 r2 
    where r1.ATTRIBUTE4 = r2.Supplier_RIB
      and r1.some_id = :new.some_ap_supplier_sites_all_id;      --> this
    ```
- if that number is larger than 0, you're executing `testrib` procedure

  - if it sends an e-mail, then yes - it'll send it 6 times

What to do? Switch to a **statement-level trigger** (instead of the row-level you currently use) as it fires once per statement, regardless number of rows affected.

Comment: Hello thank you for your update, below my explications:

Comment: please see my below feedback

Comment: This is unreadable, sorry. From what I managed to understand, you're referring to "wrong" COUNT. It is not number of rows returned by your SELECT statement in a trigger, but number of rows affected by INSERT or UPDATE on table AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL.

Comment: Yes, i count number of attribute4 for each supplier, if count>1, it means the attribute4 exists for 2 or more suppliers, in this case send emails to manager saying, the attriute4 is sharing with others suppliers.

Comment: i create another procedure: create or replace PROCEDURE ribrib
aS 
  v_count number := 0;
BEGIN
select   count(*) into v_count   from rib1 r1,rib3 r3 where r1.ATTRIBUTE4=r3.Supplier_RIB;
  if v_count > 1  then
   testrib;
  end if;
END;   after my trigger called my new procedure:    CREATE or replace TRIGGER duplicate_RIB
 AFTER  insert or update on ap_supplier_sites_all
 for each row
 begin
     ribrib;
 end;   but also the same issue 6 emails in the same time

Comment: Please, re-read what I've already said, try to understand it. Row-level trigger will fire for each row inserted or updated in AP_SUPPLIER_SITES_ALL. You have to switch to a statement-level trigger (the one that doesn't have `for each row`, to simply put it).

Comment: yes,  i removed the ligne "for each row", now i received 4 emails instead of 6, it good but my goal is receiving only one email, so my issue not resolved yet.

Comment: Any news please, i'm blocked

Comment: Not really; but, if you could create a test case - that includes CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data - as well as all code you use, we'd be able to reproduce what you have and what you do and, hopefully, help.

Comment: Hi, i change the condition:  select count(*) into x_count from rib3 r3 where r3.Supplier_RIB=:new.attribute4;   now it work correctly

Comment: I asked that (`and r1.some_id = :new.some_ap_supplier_sites_all_id;`) two days ago. OK, I'm glad you fixed it. Thank you for letting us know.